# maximum parallel http requests

Tags: php, load-testing

I would like to find the maximum parallel http requests I can make to a server without having errors both from my own server and also from the host server using http guzzle package, in an empirical dynamic way. For example I start from an initial number say 200 and if it doesn't give an error the code should automatically increase up the parallel requests until the maximum number that errors occurs.

Working with php and just developing on web, I have forgotten concepts like memoization that may help find the solution of this problem.
So let's say I have a million requests stored on a database and I would like to send them asap what should I do?

```
while(unresolved_requests()){
     
    try{

        make_the_requests(int numbers_of_parallel_requests,int first_unresolved_request_id);
        increase_the_parallel_requests();

    }catch(err){

        decrease_the_parallel_requests() 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to do load testing, use a load testing tool.**

Take a look at [JMeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter). There are many others (Wrk, Autocannon, K6, Bombardier...).

It is not trivial to develop such testing tool and get consistent results.

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking it. It may work. But I would prefer not to use another tool. So, I'll wait for other answers while checking out these load testing tools.

Comment: Worth to mention [ddosify](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify) in case you decided to use a load testing tool.